# Avoid ListBuffer while preparing an element-wise multiplication of two SparseVectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement a element-wise multiplication of two `ml.linalg.SparseVector` instances (also called a Hadamard product).

A SparseVector represents a vector, but rather than having space taken up by all the "0" values, they are omitted. The vector is represented as two lists of Indices and Values.

For example: `SparseVector(indices: [0, 100, 100000], values: [0.25, 1, 0.8])` concisely represents an array of 100,000 elements, where only 3 values are non-zero.

I now need an element-wise multiplication of two of these, and there seems to be no built-in. Conceptually, it should be simple - any indices they don't have in common are dropped, and for the indices in common, the numbers are multiplied together.

For example: `SparseVector(indices: [0, 500, 100000], values: [10, 1, 10])` when multiplied with the above should return: `SparseVector(indices: [0, 100000], values: [2.5, 8])`

Sadly, I've found no built-in for this. I have an approach for doing this in a single pass, but it isn't very scala-y, it has to build up the list in a loop as it discovers which indices are in common, and then grab the corresponding values for each index (which have the same cardinal position, but in a second array).

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

// Return a new SparseVector whose values are the element-wise product (Hadamard product)
val multSparseVectors = udf((v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector) => {
  // val commonIndexes = v1.indices.intersect(v2.indices); // Missing scale factors are assumed to have a value of 0, so only common elements remain
  // TODO: No clear way to map common indices to the values that go with those indices. E.g. no "valueForIndex" method
  // new SparseVector(v1.size, commonIndexes, commonIndexes.map(i => v1.valueForIndex(i) * v2.valueForIndex(i)).toArray);
  
  val indices = ListBuffer[Int](); // TODO: Some way to do this without mutable lists?
  val values = ListBuffer[Double]();
  var v1Pos = 0; // Current index of SparseVector v1 (we will be making a single pass)
  var v2pos = 0; // Current index of SparseVector v2 (we will be making a single pass)
  while(v1Pos < v1.indices.length && v2pos < v2.indices.length) {
    while(v1.indices(v1Pos) < v2.indices(v2pos))
      v2pos += 1; // Advance our position in SparseVector 2 until we've matched or passed the current SparseVector 1 index
    if(v2pos > v2.indices.length && v1.indices(v1Pos) == v2.indices(v2pos)) {
      indices += v1.indices(v1Pos);
      values += v1.values(v1Pos) * v2.values(v2pos);
    }
    v1Pos += 1;
  }
  new SparseVector(v1.size, indices.toArray, values.toArray);
})
spark.udf.register("multSparseVectors", multSparseVectors)
```

Can anyone think of a way that I can do this using a map or similar? My main goal is I want to avoid having to make multiple O(N) passes over the second vector to "lookup" the position of a value in the `indices` list so that I can grab the corresponding `values` entry, because this would take O(K + N*2) time when I know there's an O(K + N) solution possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution by boiling this problem into a more general one:

- [Finding the indices at which two arrays intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928122)

Given an answer to the above question (where to the two arrays `v1.indices` and `v2.indices` intersect), we can trivially use those indices to extract back the new SparseVector indices, and the values from each vector to be multiplied together.

The solution is given below:

```scala
%scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

// This fanciness from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71928709/529618 finds the indices at which two lists intersect
@tailrec
def indicesOfIntersection(left: List[Int], right: List[Int], lidx: Int = 0, ridx: Int = 0, result: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil): List[(Int, Int)] = (left, right) match { 
    case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => result.reverse
    case (l::tail, r::_) if l < r => indicesOfIntersection(tail, right, lidx+1, ridx, result)
    case (l::_, r::tail) if l > r => indicesOfIntersection(left, tail, lidx, ridx+1,  result)
    case (l::ltail, r::rtail) => indicesOfIntersection(ltail, rtail, lidx+1, ridx+1, (lidx, ridx) :: result)
}

// Return a new SparseVector whose values are the element-wise product (Hadamard product)
val multSparseVectors = udf((v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector) => {
  val intersection = indicesOfIntersection(v1.indices.toList, v2.indices.toList);
  new SparseVector(v1.size,
    intersection.map{case (x1,_) => v1.indices(x1)}.toArray,
    intersection.map{case (x1,x2) => v1.values(x1) * v2.values(x2)}.toArray);
})
spark.udf.register("multSparseVectors", multSparseVectors)
```