# Find the indices at which two arrays intersect

Tags: scala

I'm wondering if in Scala there's a decent way to get the indices at which two arrays intersect.

So given arrays:

- `a1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]`
- `a2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`

Ideally, taking advantage of the fact that both arrays are ordered and contain no duplicates.

These share common elements `a1.intersect(a2) = [10, 20, and 30]`. The index (position) at which these elements occur is different for each array.

I would like to produce a sequence of tuples with the positions from each list where they intersect:

- `intersectingIndices(a1, a2) = [(2, 0), (4, 1), (6, 2)]`

While `intersect` gives the intersecting values, I need to know the original indices and would prefer not to have to do an O(N) scan to find each one - as these arrays get very long (millions of elements). I also suspect the complexity of `intersect` is unnecessarily large given both arrays will always be sorted in advance, so a single-pass option would be preferable.

Comment: Can this lists have duplicates? _"I also suspect intersect takes O(n*log(n))"_ -  why do you suspect that?

Comment: Good question, I should have said. The lists cannot have duplicates (they are effectively ordered sets). My suspicion about the complexity of intersect is based on prior experience with algorithms for list intersection (best case O(n*log(n)) to create a hashSet, + O(n) to do all lookups)

Comment: Creating a hash set can/should be O(n).

Comment: @Alain isn't creating a hashset `O(n)`?

Comment: That's right, it is. Now that I think about it, I hadn't been thinking about hash sets when I came up with that number - I was imagining doing an O(log(N)) binary search for the index each time (times N searches)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both lists are storted, it seems fairly straightforward, just a slight variation of the "merge" phase of merge-sort.

```
@taiilrec
def intersect(
   left: List[Int], 
   right: List[Int], 
   lidx: Int = 0, 
   ridx: Int = 0,
   result: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil
): List[(Int, Int)] = (left, right) match { 
    case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => result.reverse
    case (l::tail, r::_) if l < r => intersect(tail, right, lidx+1, ridx, result)
    case (l::_, r::tail) if l > r => intersect(left, tail, lidx, ridx+1,  result)
    case (l::ltail, r::rtail) => intersect(ltail, rtail, lidx+1, ridx+1, (lidx, ridx) :: result)
}
```

Or just hash one of the lists, and then scan the other (it is still O(n), albeit somewhat more expensive, but much simpler):

```
val hashed = left.zipWithIndex.toMap
right.zipWithIndex.flatMap { case(x, idx) => hashed.get(x).map(idx -> _) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to get hung-up on syntactic matters, but is there a way to make this work for arrays or general sequences? SparseVector uses arrays of indicies/values, and I hesitate to convert these huge things to lists for the function call if I can avoid it. I tried just converting `List` args to `Seq` but wound up with a runtime error `MatchError: (WrappedArray(1391, 2953..., 49895),WrappedArray(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,..., 49998)) (of class scala.Tuple2)`

Comment: Yeah, the `Nil` and `head::tail` extractors only work for lists. You can trivially rewrite it for any seq: just replace `Nil` with `Seq()` and `head::tail` with `head+:tail`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, even the trivial eludes me, so I posted this as a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71930798/convert-function-that-works-with-listint-to-take-seqint