# Convert function that works with List[Int] to take Seq[Int]

Tags: scala

I've been provided with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71928709/529618) on another question that works with `List[Int]` to get the indices at which two lists intersect.

```scala
@tailrec
def indicesOfIntersection(left: List[Int], right: List[Int], lidx: Int = 0, ridx: Int = 0, result: List[(Int, Int)] = Nil): List[(Int, Int)] = (left, right) match { 
    case (Nil, _) | (_, Nil) => result.reverse
    case (l::tail, r::_) if l < r => indicesOfIntersection(tail, right, lidx+1, ridx, result)
    case (l::_, r::tail) if l > r => indicesOfIntersection(left, tail, lidx, ridx+1,  result)
    case (l::ltail, r::rtail) => indicesOfIntersection(ltail, rtail, lidx+1, ridx+1, (lidx, ridx) :: result)
}
```

And am hoping to convert it to one that works directly on Arrays, without doing anything inefficient (because it is used on **big** arrays)

The advice I got was

> Yeah `Nil` and `head::tail` extractors only work for lists. You can trivially rewrite it for any `seq`: just replace `Nil` with `Seq()` and `head::tail` with `head+:tail`

Unfortunately, the trivial is still over my head and I require a bit more spoon feeding :)

I took a stab with the following which passed compile-time checks, but fails at runtime:

```scala
@tailrec
def indicesOfIntersection(left: Seq[Int], right: Seq[Int], lidx: Int = 0, ridx: Int = 0, result: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq()): Seq[(Int, Int)] = (left, right) match { 
    case (l::tail, r::_) if l < r => indicesOfIntersection(tail, right, lidx+1, ridx, result)
    case (l::_, r::tail) if l > r => indicesOfIntersection(left, tail, lidx, ridx+1,  result)
    case (l::ltail, r::rtail) => indicesOfIntersection(ltail, rtail, lidx+1, ridx+1, (lidx, ridx) +: result)
    case (Seq(), _) | (_, Seq()) => result.reverse
}
```

> scala.MatchError: (WrappedArray(19, 68, 419...

*(error truncated due to essentially being a dump of my first array input)*

Thanks in advance for pointing out what I've done wrong.

---

**Update**

I've gotten a little further by updating all instances of `::` operators in the case statements to `+:` as well (although I don't understand the syntax, thinking this was just a place for destructuring).

It's running now, but I'm unsure if it's "correct" - specifically it seems that if the final case (formerly the first case) is comparing empty `Seq()` instances, they won't necessarily be considered equal just because the are both empty (unlike the former `Nil` comparison)?

---

**Update**

I've been informed in the comments that one cannot simply use `tail` on Arrays without incurring a heavy cost (presumably traversing the entire array?) so I'm still looking for a solution which replaces these nuances with something that is equally performant for Arrays (or any Seq, if you wish)

Comment: If you call that function with an `Array` it would be slower than just converting the `Array` to a `List` first.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how come? What if the array has 1 million elements and the cost of allocation/copying is non-trivial?

Comment: Sure, it is not trivial. And by calling `tail` you are paying that cost multiple times; so rather, just pay the cost once and convert it to a `List` which supports a constant `tail` or rather write another method that uses indexes instead.

Comment: Oh that is surprising. I would have though tail would be optimized to just jump to the last index of the array (whose size is known). This is why I'm asking this question, I don't know the internals of Scala. So it seems like converting this to **efficiently** support arrays is non-trivial.

Comment: `tail` returns a new collection that contains all the elements but the first one, and for arrays that is implemented with a copy because `Arrays` are mutable so you can't just have a simple view; actually, using `Arrays` in **Scala** is discouraged. - Finally, it is not only non-trivial, but it is also effectively impossible, that is why I don't like `Seq` and I discourage its use, trying to abstract over collections that all present different performance characteristics is only asking for trouble; unless you only abstract patterns of iteration like the **cats** typeclasses do.

Comment: Anyways `Seq` won't support `Array` because `Array` is not a `Seq` _(although it may be an implicit conversion)_ because `Array` is not a collection but a primitive of the runtime platform... another reason not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your `Array` using `scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq.unsafeWrapArray` and then converting it to a `View` using `.view`.

Making it a `View` will allow you to take the tail without actually copying the underlying array.

See also https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html

Comment: Note that if the underlying array is modified this method will result in weird bugs.

Comment: Yes, one must ensure the underlying array is not modified. If that's not possible then one might as well convert (copy) to a `List`